# Infragistics XamTextEditor copy to DataTable (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm working with a XamDataGrid which is bound to a DataTable.  When I type in data in the rows and I hit save (to save my data back to the database), it never saves the last row entered.  I'm guessing because I need to tab out of the cell that I'm currently entering data in and that it will only move the text to the DataTable upon edit end.  Is there a way to copy data to the DataTable as the user enters it so they don't have to tab out to force the edit end or is there a  better way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as comment but am unable to. Its hard to say without more information but have you tried adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged?

```
"{Binding Path=Something, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Yes - I already had/have this in place but it wasn't firing at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The grid should update its source if it loses focus which may not be happening especially if your save button is in a toolbar that doesn't take focus.  If that is the case, you can force the grid to end editing and commit the record by calling [ExecuteCommand](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~ExecuteCommand.html) on the XamDataGrid and passing in the [DataPresenterCommands](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterCommands_members.html).EndEditModeAndCommitRecord command.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me in the right direction. I got it to bind and trigger properly.